# My computationally intensive Numba function runs 10x slower on the GPU than on CPU. Am I missing anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, gpgpu, numba

I'ḿ testing Numba's performance and tried a dummy but computationally intense function two ways: on the CPU with parallelism enabled (and prange), and on the GPU where I see it occupies 100% of the GPU when running. Both run fine, but the CPU one takes 10X less time to complete. I was epxecting the GPU to be faster in this case, even though my GPU is not very strong (Geforce 1050 ti) and my CPU is strong (Threadripper 3970x).

Here is my CPU benchmark:

```
from numba import *
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda
import time


def benchmark():
    input_list = np.random.randint(10, size=320000)
    out = np.zeros(len(input_list))
    cpu_run_test(input_list, out)
    print('Result size: ' + str(len(out)) + ' ' + str(out))


@njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True, nogil=True)
def cpu_run_test(input_list, out):
    for step in range(len(input_list)):

        for j in range(10):
            count = 0
            for item2 in input_list:
                if input_list[step] == item2:
                    count = count + 1
            out[step] = count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("benchmark()", setup="from __main__ import benchmark", number=1))
```

And here is my GPU benchmark (same computation, just partitioning work differently to take advantage of the GPUs blocks and threads appropriately:

```
from numba import *
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda
import time


def benchmark():
    for xx in range(1):
    new_array_duration = time.time()
    input_list = np.random.randint(10, size=320000)
    new_array_duration = time.time() - new_array_duration
    print('New array duration: ' + str(new_array_duration))

    to_device_duration = time.time()
    d_array = cuda.to_device(input_list)
    to_device_duration = time.time() - to_device_duration
    print('To device duration: ' + str(to_device_duration))

    kernel_duration = time.time()
    run_test[16, 768](d_array)
    kernel_duration = time.time() - kernel_duration
    print('Kernel duration: ' + str(kernel_duration))

    to_host_duration = time.time()
    out = d_array.copy_to_host()
    to_host_duration = time.time() - to_host_duration
    print('To host duration: ' + str(to_host_duration))


@cuda.jit(fastmath=True)
def run_test(d_array):
    array_slice_len = len(d_array) / cuda.blockDim.x
    slice_start = (cuda.threadIdx.x * (cuda.blockIdx.x + 1)) * array_slice_len

    for step in prange(slice_start, slice_start + array_slice_len):
        if step > len(d_array) - 1:
            return

        for j in range(10):
            count = 0
            for item2 in d_array:
                if d_array[step] == item2:
                    count = count + 1
            d_array[step] = count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    # make_multithread(benchmark, 64)
    print(timeit.timeit("benchmark()", setup="from __main__ import benchmark", number=1))
```

Anyone can just copy and paste and run either. I'm on Linux Mint 20, Python 3.7, latest Numba (0.51) and latest cudatoolkit installed.

The results are as follows:

CPU: **15.20 secs**

GPU: **145.54 secs**

Is this correct or I am missing some optimizations for getting the GPU code running faster?

What am I missing?

Comment: Whether or not the code will run faster on a GPU depends on the operations you use, it is not a given. GPUs excel at linear algebra type operations which can be massively vectorized.

Comment: Yes, but this test function seems like one of those that should perform better on the GPU: looping through a large array and producing an array that has how many times each input array item appears in that input array. Comparisons, some additions, loops.. not sure why the cpu is faster.

Comment: Extensive branching with ifs is one case where CPUs will outperform GPUs, unless the CUDA compiler you use can somehow optimize that, or you can formulate that in a vectorized way. It is *not* the amount of operations, but the type of operations you use.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarely an answer, but way too long for a comment.

Some things I would try; altering the blocks and threads and see what happens. Also utilizing Local, Shared and Global Memory on the GPU.

Global Memory is the only one that can be set by the host and is accessible to all threads. It is also the slowest type of memory for access, so you generally want to minimize the amount of transfers and use Memory Coalescing where possible.

Shared Memory is memory that is available for all threads in one Block and is faster than global memory. Local Memory is the fastest and only visible to one thread.

Is starting prange on the GPU actually using the GPU threads? Because normaly (non-python) you don't have to invoke stuff in parallel on the GPU. Maybe that loop runs in serial instead?

You should also try to find an algorithm that does not involve branching (if there is one). If I understand your code correctly, you have a list with 320.000 items containing random integers in the range [0;10). For each item, you count how often that item appears and replace the item with the count of that item. And 10x for good measure. This will cause the items of the resulting set to oscillate between the values [0;10) and somewhat between [0;320.000), but probably more around 32.000 in general.

To make it easier to transform the algorithm by getting rid of that unpleasant oscillation, increasing the list size by factor 10 and getting rid of the loop should do the same.

As I don't speak python, here's some pseudocode for a non-branching vectorized implementation. Although I don't know if this will be faster at all, it is something I would try.

```
{l} local memory
{s} shared memory
{g} global memory

Host:
input_list{g} = (0..9)[3.200.000]
accumulator{g} = (0..0)[10]
run _1
run _2


Device Kernel _1:   
let blocksize = get_blocksize()
let threadId = get_threadId()
let globalId = get_globalId()

let localSum{s} = arr[10]
let localCopy{s} = arr[blocksize.x]

if(globalId.x < size(input_list)) {
    localCopy[threadId] = input_list[globalId]
    
    localSum[localCopy[threadId]]++
}

if(threadId.x < 10) {
    accumulator[threadId] += localSum[threadId]
}


Device Kernel _2:
let blocksize = get_blocksize()
let threadId = get_threadId()
let globalId = get_globalId()

let localAcc{l} = arr[10]

for(i = 0 to 10) {
    localAcc[i] = accumulator[i]
}

if(globalId < size(input_list)) {
    let val = input_list[globalId]
    input_list[globalId] = localAcc[val]
}
```